# What does a lipid panel measure?

Tags: cholesterol, lipids

A lipid panel measures serum cholesterol and triglycerides: https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diagnostics/17176-lipid-panel

If the subject is fasting, then, would it be accurate to state that the cholesterol and triglycerides in the blood then are either from the body metabolizing fat for fuel or converting excess glucose or fructose into adipose tissue?

If we are not fasting, then, triglycerides would be at least partially affected by what we eat if it contains fat. Since fats take longer to break down, then, it is still possible that triglycerides measured would be also including some recently consumed fats.

Additionally, the measurements are just what is in the blood at that point in time and is an inexpensive way to measure what might be built up on artery walls which is what it really is trying to measure as the goal is to essentially measure risk for cardiovascular diseases.